# Is there a way that I can tell the direction request to stay on one road while it plots the start to end?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way that I can tell the direction request to stay on one road while it plots the start to end?

### Request:

- Say Start (Lat/Lon) and End (Lat/Lon) are on the Route US1.
- Say Interstate i-95 runs parallel along Route US1 at the above Start to End segment.
- API route direction request for the above Start to End.

### Map Route Shows:

- Starts at Start point on route US1.
- Takes the exit from US1 to run the route on i-95.
- Just before the End point, takes the exit  from i-95 to US1 and ends at the End point on Route US1.

### Current Behavior:

Above Routing is understandable that Google API plots the direction on the fastest route and so API takes route i-95 which is parallel to that segment of the US1.

### My Requirement:

Is there parameter that I can specify in the below direction request to always stay on the US1 route, regardless of any faster/quicker/shorter alternate route?

```
var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a few optional parameters to that request:

1. You can provide `waypoints` (up to 8, which include origin and
   destination) but the direction will always go via those waypoints.
2. You can provide `avoid` to avoid tollways or highways (I don't know
   if that is the case in your question.
3. You can set `alternatives` to `true`. That way, Google will provide
   you more than 1 alternative to the route which may be the one you are looking for.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters (scroll down to 'Optional parameters').

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your response. To be clear with my requirement: I use the direction request for ploting a transportation project. User just selects a Route and then selects start and End Intersection on the same route. While they save their selection, Google Map API uses the just start and End Intersection (Lon/lat) to plot on the map for the user's view project location on the map (API doesn't know the selected route), so the project actaully happens on the selected route and with in the Start and End Intersection. continued in the next comment.....

Comment: So,              1. App Users won't be able select any Waypoints.                      2. Can't Avoid tollways or highways, since some of the project may actaully happen on the tollways or highways.                           3. Also showing alternatives route for user selection may not work for this transportation project plotting, rather if ApI allows to programatically select and show only the route which stays only the selected route. Not sure if google API will all the time provide the aternative which runs entirely on the selected route unless they know the selected route.

Comment: Thanks again. I think, I am using the google api (route direction) for un-intented (google) purpose. Any other api suggestion for my requirement.